# Properly venting 2 bathrooms using existing roof penetration (boots)

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan

After some mold and mildew issues our bathrooms, I discovered that the bathroom fans in each room were routed directly into a 90 and up through the roof (and one was undersized to begin with).
I'm trying to avoid additional roof penetrations (2-year-old 1/12 EPDM roof), don't have access to exterior walls in either bathroom, and don't want to cut through and reinforce a bunch of joists.

I have verified leaks have stopped (except for through the hole on the first pipe and around the tape). Air mold testing numbers came back fine.

The first bathroom is roughly 50 square feet, with most of the ceiling out due to previous mold issues and now revealing electrical issues that are another matter. Here is the fan.
[image: Fan into 90° with leaky tape and holes in pipe]

[image: Ceiling structure with existing vent]

I could relocate it closer to the shower and use (insulated) flex pipe (maybe even smooth interior) for a gradual bend, but there's only so much I can do in 2x10 rafters. Pipe is 4 inch and terminates through a boot on the roof. No damper in addition to the one on the fan itself, just your basic vent pipe cap (to which I added some screen). Any other suggestions?

The larger bathroom is roughly 100 square feet, 2 sinks and a shower/tub. It was originally set up with an 80 CFM fan also routed into a 90° and straight up like the other bathroom but I don't have a picture of that. This is the pipe viewed through the hole from the previous fan (owner didn't fold in the mounting tabs and I got a little frustrated so the hole's a bit messy.[image: Fan hole with rusty pipe]

There's electrical wires going to other nearby lights that will need to be moved (to a junction box is easiest way to lengthen them without re-running, I guess), and an adjacent light nearby makes space tight. We could obviously take that light out and replace it with a lighted fan (that light's been burnt out for a while and the room is still plenty bright), and I'd only have to deal with going through one joist. The other option I've considered is one of the wall/ceiling mount fans (not the loud Broans). Here's the nearby light and the existing hole.
[image: All the lights and holes]

From what I've read, inline duct-boosters are loud and often ineffective, the proper inline duct fans require 8' of duct length between inlet and/or outlet (which I don't have without modifying joists and adding roof penetrations). I'm basically down to something like [this](https://www.coolcomponents.com/HiFlo-Pro_p_211.html) with one of their [duct boxes (with 3" pipe ?!)](https://www.coolcomponents.com/Ceiling-Duct-Box--4x8-Insulated_p_308.html), but they also show those as both 102 and 130 CFM on their site and the idea of computer fans (basically), even IP68, in this application, worries me. Obviously I could do an under-powered attic fan on a curb or maybe even something like [this](https://roofvents.com/roof-mounted-power-attic-ventilator/) wile still using our existing boot (there's no flange at the bottom on ours) but they're a couple weeks out and I'm desperate to get this back together.

Surely I'm over-thinking this as I've spent literally days searching. Can anybody provide the right/quick/easy/obvious solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Ruskes, I need to know if there's alternatives to just replacing fans and exiting directly into 90s and up through the roof, the way it was originally. All fan manufacturers say not to do that, for obvious reasons. Haven't had luck finding inline or remote options that will work. Space constraints. Condensate a concern too in our climate.

Comment: "(to a junction box is easiest way to lengthen them without re-running, I guess)" If you do this, make sure that the JBs are permanently accessible by simply removing a blank cover plate. You _cannot_ bury them in the ceiling in a way the requires more than screwdriver access to get to them. Also, this is a well detailed, well laid out question, _especially_ for a first question! Well done!

Comment: I'm not understanding what is the problem that you are trying to solve here?  It sounds like you are concerned about the vent duct being too short, in which case you could just buy a 4" slinky duct and stretch out as far as needed.

Comment: Also, am I seeing this wrong, or is there a 2" gap in the roof sheathing?

Comment: Glad you made that point. Though that should have been obvious, I hadn't originally thought about that. Easy enough to re-think though. Thanks for the kind words, too (my original reply was to a guy who posted only "TL;DR").

@RobertChapin, the fans both previously exit(ed) directly into 90 bends and up through the roof, which negatively affects blower performance and led to moisture and condensate issues. I want to use existing roof penetrations but improve flow, if possible. Space constraints and wiring are issues. 
Yes, that's a gap between sheeting in the first picture. Foam+EPDM above.